# OMP PRAGMA IGNORED with R CMD SHLIB compilation R function lowess

Tags: r, parallel-processing, openmp, pragma

Hi i am trying to parallel R function lowess with openMP with pragma parallel for loop

```
  static
void clowess(double *x, double *y, int n,
     double f, int nsteps, double delta,
     double *ys, double *rw, double *res)
{
    int i, iter, j, last, m1, m2, nleft, nright, ns;
    Rboolean ok;
    double alpha, c1, c9, cmad, cut, d1, d2, denom, r, sc;

omp_set_num_threads(8);

if (n < 2) {
ys[0] = y[0]; return;
}

/* nleft, nright, last, etc. must all be shifted to get rid of these: */
x--;
y--;
ys--;


/* at least two, at most n points */
ns = imax2(2, imin2(n, (int)(f*n + 1e-7)));
#ifdef DEBUG_lowess
REprintf("lowess(): ns = %d\n", ns);
#endif

/* robustness iterations */

iter = 1;
while (iter <= nsteps+1) {
nleft = 1;
nright = ns;
last = 0;   /* index of prev estimated point */
i = 1;      /* index of current point */

#pragma omp parallel for
for(;;) {
    if (nright < n) {
 }
}
```

here is example of lowess function that i try to parallelize
i just add omp_set_num_threads(8) and #pragma omp parallel for and i set my vim terminal env with setenv PKG_LIBS -lgomp and setenv PKG_CXXFLAGS -fopen but when i compiled with R CMD SHLIB it say that my pragma are ignored but i dont understand why? i need pragma in order to parallelize this function lowess

thank you my friends

Comment: 1. It should be `-fopenmp` not `-fopen`.
2. The loop doesn't have a format that is support by OpenMP. The compiler cannot know how to divide the loop.

Comment: so i set env correctly now and put pragma around a standard loop like for(i=0;i<10; i++) but the pragma omp parallel for are still ignored

Comment: Can you give the exact error message?

Comment: in the source code https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/library/stats/src/lowess.c 
i put pragma  before line 233 and it gives me the warning
warning: ignoring #pragma omp parallel [-Wunknown-pragmas]
   #pragma omp parallel for

Comment: What compiler are you using and can you give the complete command? Either your compiler doesn't support OpenMP or you didn't enabled it right.

Comment: I set the env with setenv PKG_LIBS -lgomp and setenv PKG_CXXFLAGS -fopenmp

i use the command R CMD SHLIB lowessomp.c to try and compile it 

i believe the compiler is a gcc 64 bit

it's strange since if i compile another one it reads in the pragmas correctly

Comment: This is something specific to your `make` system. With compiler I mean `gcc` or `icc` etc. It would also be useful to know how exactly the compiler is invoked.

Comment: gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include    -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches  -m64 -mtune=generic  -c lowess_omp.c -o lowess_omp.o

this is it ?

Comment: And there you see that `-fopenmp` is missing. Try to set `PKG_CFLAGS` to `-fopenmp`. `PKG_CXXFLAGS` should only be used by a `c++` compiler like `g++`.

Comment: ah i see it was able to compile with the pragma, thank you for your help